# How to filter Xdocument and return Xdocument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, linq-to-xml

My application gets data from SharePoint web service (using SOAP and CAML query), I am using a Xdocument doc to store retrieved xmlNode and then assign xdocument to XMLDataSource which is binned to gridView.

Now I need to filter the Xdocument before binding, to pick only those records where an element (ows_Partner_x0020_Type) matches a variable.

I am trying like this :

```
doc = doc.Descendants(z + "row").Where(rows => rows.Attribute("ows_Partner_x0020_Type").Value == Partner_Type.SelectedValue);
```

or

```
var bar = doc.Descendants(z + "row").Where(rows => rows.Attribute("ows_Partner_x0020_Type").Value == Partner_Type.SelectedValue);
```

but the problem is that return type of above LINQ is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>`

which is quit nothing like XDocument, which is required format to bind to XMLDataSource as doc.ToString().

Hope I am able to explain the problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Vishal

Answer (score 4):

If you're just trying to create a document with those elements, you can use:

```
XDocument filteredDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("root", bar));
```

(That will create a document with a root element of `<root>`, and all the elements you're interested in directly under that.)

Not quite sure about all the binding parts - I strongly suspect there may be a better alternative - but this will certainly give you a new `XDocument`.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working the problem is that ist creating the same structure thrice. like <a><z:row></a> base {System.Xml.Linq.XContainer}: <a><z:row></a> Declaration: null
    DocumentType: null
    NodeType: Document
    Root: <a><z:row></a>

Comment: BTW the type of bar is : System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>

Comment: @VishalSachdeva: It's very hard to tell what you've really got. What happens if you dump out the whole document *as an XML document*? I suspect you've just got 3 matching rows...